# Couldn't match expected type `IO ()' with actual type `a0 -> m0 a0'

Tags: haskell

Here's my code:

```
doSomething :: IO Bool -> IO () -> IO ()
doSomething cond body = cond >>= ( \condition -> if condition then return else body )
```

It gives me this error:

```
Couldn't match expected type `IO ()' with actual type `a0 -> m0 a0'
In the expression: return
In the expression: if condition then return else body
In the second argument of `(>>=)', namely
  `(\ condition -> if condition then return else body)'
```

I also tried this equivalent notation:

```
whileM :: IO Bool -> IO () -> IO ()
whileM cond body = do
                     condition <- cond
                     if condition then return else body
```

but I am getting more or less the same notation. I understand that the error is saying that the function expects me to return a Monad but instead I am returning a function which transforms `a0` into a monad `m a0`. How can I fix this?

Comment: Try `return ()` instead of just `return`

Comment: Also, won't your function just always return `undefined`...?

Comment: The undefined line shouldn't be there it was a place holder before I implemented the function

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Unlike in (pretty much all) other languages, in Haskell, `return` doesn't mean "terminate this code and go back to the next line of what called it".

In Haskell, it (roughly) means "wrap this thing up in a monad".  In the context of the `do` notation, this often occurs at the place in the code where control is given back to the "caller" (again, this isn't really the correct word, but will do in this analogy).

Hence, `return` needs a parameter here (the thing to be wrapped up)....  `return` is of type `Monad m => a -> m a`, but your function is returning type `IO ()`.  The thing you will therefore need to wrap up is of type `()`, a type with just one element, '()' itself.

Change `return` to `return ()`, and see if that works.

Comment: Perfect! Thanks for the help! I probably should of just looked at the function definition of return!